# XSD Walker - Traverse an XSD with a series of XML Tag openings and closings as input

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xerces, xsom

Basically what I want is to create a state transition diagram representation of an XSD. It's not a simple state diagram; it should reflect compositors (All, Choice, Sequence), min and max occurrences, and derivation (restriction, extension). What the XSD traverser must be able to do is to update its position in the state diagram representation of an XSD every time an XML tag is fed to it. It should rollback its position on close of a tag. And it should be able to determine if feeding an XML tag to it would invalidate the XML i.e. the traverser cannot find a path given the XML tag.

I've been using XSOM and it's functor-visitor architecture, but I can't implement compositors, occurences, and derivations using XSOM.

Any one of you know any library that already does this?

Or any ideas on how to construct such state transition diagram?

Or better yet, you guys provide links to codes for XML Validators? This is basically what XML validators do when validating an XML against an XSD right?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to build an XML validator, which is a state machine. It takes ans XSD as input and builds a state machine. Then the machine in run over an XML and figures if it's valid. And you want the running visualized?

XSOM is the library you use for parsing the XSD. Here's a [user guide](https://xsom.java.net/userguide.html) which outlines the API. The XSD contents will become the states for your state machine. This should work similar to building state machines for regular expressions.

I'd start by creating some states for simple elements, for example take this schema ([more examples here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_example.asp)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="shiporder" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

You'd create a `start` and an `end` state. Then create a state `shiporder` for the element. You start in the `start` state. When you encounter the `<shiporder>` tag, there's a transition from `start` to `shiporder` state. When you encounter string content in the `shiporder` state, you'd stay in the `shiporder` state. When you encounter the end tag `</shiporder>` you'd go to the `end` state. If you encounter something without a defined transition, the validation fails.

Other elements would of course require a more sophisticates logic. For example an `<xs:sequence>` would have transitions to multiple elements.

Then you'd use SAX to read the XML. The events emitted are the input events for your state machine which trigger the transitions.

In the end you'll have one or a few accepting states. When the machines stops in one of those, the XML is valid.

For the state machine you can probably use one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875317/recommended-fsm-finite-state-machine-library-for-java). Maybe you find something to visualize those, or you use something like a [DFA Simulator](http://home.arcor.de/kai.w1986/dfasimulator/).

Comment: That is what I want. Creating the state diagram is quite straightforward if I only think about the possible children for a given element. However, I am having a difficult time creating state transitions logics for sequences, choices, min-max occurrences, extension/resitriction. I am asking for a way to implement state transition logics for those.

Comment: Do you know how to build a state machine for a regular expression? There should be plenty of resources, for example [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwsU2LPs85U). And your sequences `ab`, choices `a|b`, min-max `a{3,5}` all exist in regular expressions too, only there you have characters instead of tags, so you should be able to use the same methods and principles. Extensions and restrictions might need a special treatment though.

Answer (score 1):

> Or better yet, you guys provide links to codes for XML Validators?
>   This is basically what XML validators do when validating an XML
>   against an XSD right?

Take a look at [The Apache Xerces Project](http://xerces.apache.org/index.html).  Since you've tagged your question for Java, look specifically at the [Xerces2 Java Parser](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/), a fully compliant, validating XML parser.

It is possible to have Xerces build a [reusable grammar](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-grammars.html) for a given XML Schema.  Check out the [xni.XMLGrammarBuilder sample](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples-xni.html#XMLGrammarBuilder).

Xerces code is well written, and its implementation of XML and XSD (including compositors, occurrences, and derivations) is rock solid.  It would serve as a good foundation and a good source of implementational ideas for the state transition diagram you seek to build.